# How to change the default font for all jQuery Mobile texts

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to override the jQuery mobile default font for my entire website.

I have seen that there is the jQuery theme roller, but I think it's a little too much to add an entire theme just to change the font.

Is there a selector in css that would help me to select all the texts to then apply my font?

Comment: Use your developer tools, in most modern browsers you can select an element on the page and see what CSS rules apply to the element, you'll also be able to see exactly what line of the style-sheet the code can be found. `F12` seems to be the standard way of accessing developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is look at the jQuery Mobile CSS, figure out what selector the font is currently set at, and then override that value for that selector in your own CSS.

Comment: So there's no selector to select all the texts at once (including labels, buttons, ...)?

Comment: @Distwo - html { ... } would set the font for the entire page, but you need to have a selector as specific or more specific than the jQuery Mobile selector to override its value (otherwise, the jQuery Mobile selector would take precedence).

Comment: For many reasons, Is a very bad idea to change JQuery Mobile CSS. Just create your own style and override the JQM's font.

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

You can simply set it like this:

```
* {
    font: 14px Calibri,Arial !important;
}
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AzXdT/

## Final notes

If you want to find more about how to customize jQuery Mobile page and widgets then take a look at this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**. It comes with a lot of working examples, including why is !important necessary for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: this will also change fontawesome-like fonts

Answer (score 1):

these are the classes I have found so far:

```
.ui-body-a, .ui-body-a input, .ui-body-a select, .ui-body-a textarea, .ui-body-a button, .ui-btn-up-a,
.ui-body-b, .ui-body-b input, .ui-body-b select, .ui-body-b textarea, .ui-body-b button, .ui-btn-up-b,
.ui-body-c, .ui-body-c input, .ui-body-c select, .ui-body-c textarea, .ui-body-c button, .ui-btn-up-c,
.ui-body-d, .ui-body-d input, .ui-body-d select, .ui-body-d textarea, .ui-body-d button, .ui-btn-up-d,
.ui-dialog > *, .ui-widget input
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find the following line in the jquery-mobile css file and modify it to specify the font you want.

```
.ui-body-a, .ui-body-a input, .ui-body-a select, .ui-body-a textarea, .ui-body-a button {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

If you're using the -b, -c etc. styles you'll also need to modify them